# All polyhedron vertices do not plot

Tags: plotting

Only bottom half of the icosahedron shows up in ListPlot3D

```
PolyhedronData["Icosahedron"]
PolyhedronData["Icosahedron", "VertexCoordinates"]
ListPlot3D[ PolyhedronData["Icosahedron", "VertexCoordinates"], 
 PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> All]
```

How to include all points and connecting planes without copying points to input?

Comment: What is your goal? To get what `PolyhedronData["Icosahedron"]` does? If so why not use `PolyhedronData["Icosahedron"]`? `ListPlot3D` is for functions, `ListSurfacePlot3D` would be more appropriate but there are to few points. You can go with `Graphics3D+GraphicsComplex` at the end.

Comment: `ListPointPlot3D`?

Comment: Sorry, actually I wanted to be able to label /identify each  vertex from Polyhedron data to show on the image..  like P6={(1 + Sqrt[5])/( 2 Sqrt[10 - 2 Sqrt[5]]), 1/2, -(1/Sqrt[10 - 2 Sqrt[5]])}